# How to calculate APR by example

Tags: php, economics

I have such example: 
http://www.calcolatoremutui.it/tan-e-taeg/
I need to calculate TAEG (APR) but I don't understand how to calculate "r".
By this article r= 5.25% . Any ideas where did they take 5.25? 
I need to write a calculator for this: [image: TAE]

Comment: this question is off topic here. Anyway r is the value that you are looking for. It's the interest rate that you apply to the capital to get the reimbursment plan. I think for what you are trying to achieve this is not what you are looking for

Comment: you should look for a financial library in php. there are plenty and have these functions already built in